# Generating waves with fluid sim in 2.9

Tags: fluid-simulation, mantaflow

I would like to generate waves for my scene. But my wave generator is currently not working as I would like it to. [image] As You can see the water seems to be compressed somehow and no waves are generated. These are my current settings:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Edit:
the [Blend File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15sxfDC63Sd_jxCHSWVqKnrSaAKbiu8Tg/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: please provide blend file so we can check it out...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your domain isn't all the way to the bottom of the obstacle, that's why there is an air gap at the bottom. Also you could try to move the object horizontally to get more water moving.